# Why WebSockets use handshake to connect with server?

Tags: html, websocket

I have created my personal project using WebSocket API,

One thing came cross my mind as question while I have read WebSocket Spec from w3c.

Why WebSockets use handshake to connect with server?

I can't try to connect to server directly using socket?

Thanks, Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very precise, but I think I know where you are heading. Correct me if I am wrong.

The new thing is: by using the WebSocket Upgrade header (within the "handshake"), you can invoke a low-latency bi-directional connection to the server with a normal HTTP request to e.g. port 80. The full-duplex connection then goes through server:80.

> I can't try to connect to server directly using socket?

You mean plain TCP socket? You can always try, you can try any port, any protocol, but what do you want to achieve? If you know that the HTTP connection to server:80 is upgradable to a WebSocket connection, you can code the corresponding client yourself, starting with a plain TCP socket. However, since you already know that you want to connect to a WebSocket server, you should rather use an established WebSocket client, as modern browsers provide.

Answer (score 0):

The handshake allows WebSocket connections to be used together with normal HTTP(S) traffic and also to be used on the same ports. Another purpose of the handshake is to enforce CORS (cross-origin) security policies.

The handshake is not the only thing that prevents a WebSocket connection from being used with a normal TCP server. Each data frame of the WebSocket protocol has leading header data. This allows WebSockets to be a message based protocol (rather than raw streaming like TCP) and adds support for direct binary data support and also includes masking data (to protect WebSocket connections from broken intermediaries.

If you need to connect from a browser to a raw TCP service then you can use [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) which is a WebSocket to TCP bridge/proxy. **Disclaimer**: I made websockify.